# How can I Recording a UDP stream in segments, FFmpeg

Tags: html, windows, ffmpeg, udp

I'm looking for a way to record a UDP stream continuously in 30 minutes segments and encode live on the GPU. I want the recording to have the date and time burned into the clip and do it continuously (24/7).

I have tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://source:port -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 1800 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 show_{Date}_{Time}.mp4
```

`{Date}` and `{Time}` are variable holding the time of when FFmpeg starts.

This records my segments correctly, however, if there is a loss in signal in the stream, it FFmpeg crashes and doesn't continue recording or start itself back up and this does not have the current time or date burned into the output video.

I need it to be playable in html5, this is why I did mp4.

Comment: why not just put the ffmpeg in a while loop?

Comment: Doing it that way, you're going to have missing frames between the switching of the ffmpeg commands.

Comment: i tried doing while loop. i get pixelated at the start and end of the video and i need to specify it to start at every 30 minutes.

Comment: The only way to properly do it is using the API. Open the UDP stream and get the frames. Every 30 minutes open a new output file. This way the original input stream is still open and receiving the correct frames. You cannot do this in a script. UDP is raw data and ffmpeg needs to sync before being able to get a proper first frame, that is why you are getting the pixelated frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

I set up a batch file that runs on task scheduler. Triggers every 30 minutes.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -y -i {udp} -vf "drawtext=fontfile=calibrib.tff:fontsize=25:text='{ChannelName} %{localtime}': x=10: y=10: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x000000" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -c:v h264_nvenc -r 25 -threads 0  -b:v 1M -profile:v main -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 10M -sc_threshold 0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -t 00:30:00 {output}\{ChannelName}\{ChannelName}_{year}_{monthno}_{day}__{Hours}_{Minutes}_{Seconds}.mp4
```

The file name in `{ }` is my variables.

After the file is outputted im running a trim function.

The Trim function selects all the .mp4 files from a folder to trim the first minute of the video.

Using `-ss 00:01:00` and `-t 00:31:00` but without encoding so i am using `-codec copy -map 0 output.mp4`